# "If $x$ is a non-unit, then $1-ux$ is a unit"

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, local-rings

I don't understand these two lines from my book. We are given that $R$ is a local ring.

> If every $2$-generator submodule is cyclic and $Ra$, $Rb$ are given, then $Ra+Rb=Rc$, hence $a=xc,b=yc,c=ua+vb$, so $c=uxc+vb$. If $x$ is a non-unit, then $1-ux$ is a unit, so $Ra\subseteq Rc \subseteq Rb$.

First, from the definition of a local ring, if $x$ is a non-unit, then $1-x$ is. But how can we deduce that $1-ux$ is?

Is it a typo? If not, what's the significance of $ux$? Where does it come up? I can only see that rearranging the equations in the text we get $c(1-ux)=vb$.

Comment: It's not specified, so I guess not. We only know it's local

Comment: I've edited my answer to include the noncommutative case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $x$ is a non-unit, then so is $ux$ for any $u$. This is true in any commutative ring. Otherwise we'd have
$$(ux)^{-1}ux=((ux)^{-1}u)x=1$$
This contradicts the assumption that $x$ is not a unit.

If the ring is noncommutative we can still obtain the result that $ux$ is not a unit from the fact that the nonunits form an ideal in a local ring.

Answer (score 2):

$1-ux$ can not be in the maximal ideal as $x$ is and hence $ux$ is.  And since we have a local ring, any element not in the maximal ideal must be a unit.

Comment: The O.P. didn't say $R$  is  a local ring.

Comment: Yes, we are given that $R$ is a local ring